# How to mock a directory in .net for a TestMethod in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to .NET so here is my question.

I need to generate a excel document.
In my test method I need to send a path to my folder.
How can I mock this in order to not have the build failed?

Thank you in advance.

This is what I have now:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExportReoccuringRoutes()
{
    // Arrange

    var path = "d:";
    ...........................
    // Act

    var file = _routeTemplateService.ExportReoccuringRoutes(path,
    reocurringRouteSearch);
```

Comment: We need to see the method you are testing to know exactly what you're looking for. If you are looking for a mocking-framework i would recommend NSubstitute

Comment: NOTE: the path `d:` is not guaranteed to exist on every platform.  I highly recommend using something like `Path.GetTempPath()` to get a path that is guaranteed to exist in the temp directory.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx